# In Go (golang), how to iterate two arrays, slices, or maps using one `range`

Tags: go, range

To iterate over an array, slice, string, map, or channel, we can use

```
for _, x := range []int{1, 2, 3} {
  // do something
}
```

How can I iterate over two slices or maps simultaneously? Is there something like following in python?

```
for x, y in range([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]):
    print x, y
```

Comment: You cannot. Some programming is needed.

Comment: Appreciated if can explain why giving me a downvote

Comment: Are your slices same length? If yes, you can use index returned by `range` for both of them.

Comment: @Ainar-G, you should probably make that an answer (IMO it's the best one).

Comment: @Ainar-G yes they're in same length

Comment: If range is not 'must have' requirement then you could do this with classic for loop, even when lengths are different http://play.golang.org/p/enNe0o0Jif

Comment: @Omie that's helpful, thanks

Comment: A reason for wanting to do this is to avoid bounds checking, thereby making the code faster.  Bounds checking is quite bad at slowing things down.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You cannot, but if they are the same length you can use the index from `range`.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    r1 := []int{1, 2, 3}
    r2 := []int{11, 21, 31}

    if len(r1) == len(r2) {
        for i := range r1 {
            fmt.Println(r1[i])
            fmt.Println(r2[i])
        }
    }
}
```

It returns

```
1
11
2
21
3
31
```

Comment: Don't need to specify `_`. Use just:
`for i := range r1 { ... }`

Comment: Does not work with strings, which makes things hard.

Answer (score 13):

If your slices are the same length, use `range` like this:

```
for i := range x {
    fmt.Println(x[i], y[i])
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You can do this, at the cost of creating a new array (which may or may not be a deal breaker for you)

```
for _, i := range append([]int{1, 2, 3}, []int{4, 5, 6, 7}...) {
    fmt.Printf("%v\n", i)
}
```

Note it works with different length arrays.  See https://play.golang.org/p/DRCI_CwSjA for a playground example.